# Spark: how to process tree aggregation and statistic

Tags: apache-spark

I have a description of file system in form of a csv:

```
path;size;inode;type
/folder1/folder1.1;5;1;d
/folder1/folder1.1/file1;10;1;f
/folder1/folder1.1/file2;30;2;f
/folder1/folder1.1/folder1.1.1;5;4;d
/folder1/folder1.1/folder1.1.1/file3;300;5;f
/folder1/folder1.1/folder1.1.1/file4;20;6;f
/folder1/folder1.2;5;7;d
/folder1/file5;30;8;f
/folder1/file6;70;9;f
....
```

If I put this information in a RRD I will have 4 columns and I could make easy aggregation such as the sum of the size.

However here my goal would be to have a aggregation by folder of different stat such as:

- Recursive file count per folder
- Recursive total size of each folder
- Recursive mean size of file for each folder

If I stop to those 3 values my result could look like this :

```
path;file count;total size of folder;mean file size in folder
/folder1;6;475;52
/folder1/folder1.1;4;365;73
/folder1/folder1.1/folder1.1.1;2;320;160
/folder1/folder1.2;0;0;0
```

I have several questions about that kind a treatment :

- Is it relevant to use Spark for such calculation ( I have almost 500 Go of CSV to handle) ?
- If relevant, what would be the best way to approach the problem, should I split my path column and do sub aggregation or should I use method such as `TreeReduce` and `TreeAggregate` or should I use an other way ?

Thanks for any advise on how to handle such problem and feel free to move this question to any Stack site if it belongs elsewhere.